# How can I restrict null values from being stored in my array?

Tags: java, arrays

Unfortunately, my instructor won't let me to use Lists for this assignment.

I want to restrict null values from being stored in my array. I tried to use an if statement but it's not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(messages(3, 10));
}

public static String message(int n) {

        String message = null;

        if ((n % 3 != 0) && (n % 5 != 0)){
            message = null;
        } else if((n % 3 == 0) && (n % 5 == 0)) {
            message = n + ": FizzBuzz";
        } else if (n % 3 == 0) {
            message = n + ": Fizz";
        } else if (n % 5 == 0) {
            message = n + ": Buzz";
        } 

        return message;
 }

public static String[] messages(int start, int end) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (end < start) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    } else {

    String[] msgArray = new String[end - start];

    int j = 0;

    for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                String theMsg = message(i);


 /* Where I need help */

 // I'm trying to use the if statement to restrict 
 //all null values from being stored in my msgArray */  

                if(theMsg != null) {



                msgArray[j] = theMsg;

                }
                j++;
        }

    System.out.println();

    for(String s: msgArray) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    return msgArray;
        }
    }
```

Desired Output

```
3: Fizz
5: Buzz
6: Fizz
9: Fizz
```

Actual Output

```
 3: Fizz
 null
 5: Buzz
 6: Fizz
 null
 null
 9: Fizz
```

Comment: If you don't want to print `null`, then put an `if` around the `System.out.println` to prevent `null` from being printed.

Comment: Hey. I don't want them stored in the array. So when I go to print msgArray down below using the for each loop, I'm still getting the 'Actual Output' you see above.

Comment: your code looks suspicious. Where are you filling msgArray[j] with theMsg?

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to tell what posters really want.  Looking just at the output you want, I can imagine that some might think they had to avoid storing nulls in the array--but to get that output, you don't need to avoid storing them, you just need to avoid printing them.  People can become fixated on a certain way to solve a problem and miss better ways.  If there's a _different_ reason why you need an array with no nulls--either the array will be used for something else, or your instructor told you to create an array with no nulls--then OK, the answers show you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a an array, you specify a size. The array then get created and populated with a default values. In this case, that's `null` for `String`s (it's `0` for `int[]`s). There isn't a way around this. You have to specify the correct length from the creation of the array and *this length does not change*. So you have two options:

1. Somehow calculate the number of actual, non-null values *before creating your array*, then create an array with that size instead of your current calculation. This involves a lot of change in your logic so,
2. I would recommending just creating a new array from your current array and check to see if a value is `null` before you put it in.

See below:

```
// inside your function
// instead of returning msgArray, create a new array and modify it.

// get the count of values that aren't null
int nonNull = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < msgArray.length; index++) {
    if (msgArray[index] != null) nonNull++;
}

// create the new array because you can't change the size of your other array
String[] newMsgArray = new String[nonNull];

// populate the array
int newIndex = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < msgArray.length; index++) {
    if (msgArray[index] != null) {
        newMsgArray[newIndex] = msgArray[index];
        newIndex++;
    }
}

return newMsgArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating an array of (end - start) size that will be initialised with null elements. Then some of its indexes will be overwritten. So the null elements are still there and cannot be removed (Java array). A solution might be copying the full indexes into another array or allocate the right array size at first.

Answer (score 0):

Put the j++ statement inside the if block and try

```
            if(theMsg != null) {



            msgArray[j] = "dan";
            j++;
            }
```

Comment: Not good enough.  That will just move the `null`s to a different place in the output.

Answer (score 0):

A more optimal approach would be to use `List`s. But since that isn't permitted, then you can make these 2 changes in your code,

1. you can move `j++` inside your `if` block.
2. to remove all the remaining `null` in your array, you can put `msgArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(msgArray, 0, j);` just after your if statement.

**Output**

```
3: Fizz
5: Buzz
6: Fizz
9: Fizz
[Ljava.lang.String;@6d06d69c
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(messages(3, 10));
    }

    public static String message(int n) {
        String message = null;

        if ((n % 3 != 0) && (n % 5 != 0)) {
            message = null;
        } else if ((n % 3 == 0) && (n % 5 == 0)) {
            message = n + ": FizzBuzz";
        } else if (n % 3 == 0) {
            message = n + ": Fizz";
        } else if (n % 5 == 0) {
            message = n + ": Buzz";
        }

        return message;
    }

    public static String[] messages(int start, int end) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (end < start) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            String[] msgArray = new String[end - start];
            int j = 0;

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                String theMsg = message(i);


                /* Where I need help */

                // I'm trying to use the if statement to restrict 
                //all null values from being stored in my msgArray */  

                if (theMsg != null) {
                    msgArray[j] = theMsg;
                    j++; //Change #1
                }
            }

            msgArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(msgArray, 0, j); //Change #2

            System.out.println();

            for (String s: msgArray) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            return msgArray;
        }
    }
}
```